# i have thes exam and i dont know what is the problem in my answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Write a Python code snippet use 'if-elif' flow control along with a 'while' loop that will:

1. Instruct a user to input a number that is greater than 0 and less than or equal to 10 and store the input as a floating-point value in a variable
2. If the input number is greater than 0 and less than or equal to 10,
3. use a 'while' loop in order to add the number to itself until the sum exceeds a value of 100.
4. After the sum has exceeded a value of 100, use the print statement to output the sum
5. Otherwise, output the message 'You did not enter a value between 0 and 10'

**My Answer :**

```
inval = float(input('Input a number greater than zero and less than or equal to 10: '))
if inval > 0 and inval <= 10:
    while inval < 100:
        inval += inval
        continue
    else:
        print(inval)
elif inval <= 0 or inval > 10:
    print('You did not enter a value between 0 and 10')
```

Comment: My guess: `inval < 100` should be `inval <= 100`.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? As a side note you don't need the `continue` and `else`. Remove those and unindent `print`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your answer is not acceptable is because the code should return `100.0` for input like `6.25`. But, your code returns `200.0` because of your while condition. You can just add an equal sign(=) to solve this problem. And also, I removed unnecessary parts from your code.

```
inval = float(input('Input a number greater than zero and less than or equal to 10: '))
if inval > 0 and inval <= 10:
    while inval <= 100:
        inval += inval
    print(inval)
else:
    print('You did not enter a value between 0 and 10')
```

Comment: Requirement 3 says the sum "exceeds 100.0," so your less than or equal to condition is not correct.

Comment: @PaulCornelius You should think about this again.

Comment: Duh! The answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only thing that may be wrong is the condition of the While loop (u should put it `inval <= 100`).
However, the problem could be on the else inside the loop; because, its not "efficient", after the inval value is greater than 100 it will print the value even if the else is not there.
See:

```
inval = float(input('Input a number greater than zero and less than or equal to 10: '))
if inval > 0 and inval <= 10:
    while inval <= 100:
        inval += inval
    print(inval)

elif inval <= 0 or inval > 10:
    print('You did not enter a value between 0 and 10')
```

I don't see other problem in your code :)